# Linux equivalent of Powershell get-process to find ProductVersion

Tags: debian

Is there a Linux equivalent to the powershell `get-process -id 1234 | select *`

In Powershell I can do this and get a hold load of information about a process. The one I'm particularly interested in is **ProductVersion**.

Basically I am moving some Windows Apps to run on **Wine**, and as part of my monitoring of them I need to know the current **ProductVersion**.

Example:

- I have an application whose .exe file is called *MyApp.exe*
- It is AppVersion 1.0.
- It is launched via a Desktop.file which runs *MyApp.exe*
- 
- I now have an updated version of the app (1.1).
- The file *MyApp.exe* becomes *MyApp.exe.OLD*
- and the new file is re-named to *MyApp.exe*
- By re-naming it like this I don't need to modify the Desktop file / monitoring script etc.

I need a way of checking what version of the App is running so it can be recorded.

(ultimately there will be apx 50 instances of this app over multiple servers. And there could be 4 / 5 different versions running at any given time)

Comment: There's nothing like that in POSIX (or Linux), but you could probably use Win32 APIs for it inside Wine.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I'll give it a go and see what I get. Cheers.